# Google sheets script send one email instead of many

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I have a script that checks data from sheet and if number from one column is bigger than 19, then it sends an notification email with the information from row.

I have new data every day so it sends around 1-10 emails per day.

I would like to have just one email with the data from all the rows instead of many emails with the data from separate rows.

Is that somehow doable?

Thanks!

```
function sendEmail() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('sheet'); 
  const data = sh.getRange('B2:D75'+sh.getLastRow()).getValues();
  data.forEach(r=>{
     let overdueValue = r[2];  
     if (overdueValue > 19){ // if value is bigger than 19 then send email
         let name = r[0];
         let message ='https:/' + name + '    ' + 'https://' + name ;
         let subject = 'Subject: ' + name
         MailApp.sendEmail('example@gmail.com', subject, message); 
     }
  });
    
}
```

Comment: In your script, the value of `r[0]` is used as the subject of the email. In this case, if one email is sent, what subject do you want to use?

Comment: It can be just "Subject"

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function sendEmail() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('sheet');
  const data = sh.getRange('B2:D75' + sh.getLastRow()).getValues();
  const messages = data.reduce((ar, r) => {
    let overdueValue = r[2];
    if (overdueValue > 19) {
      let name = r[0];
      let message = 'https:/' + name + '    ' + 'https://' + name;
      ar.push(message);
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);

  let subject = "Subject"; // Please set the subject of the email.
  MailApp.sendEmail('example@gmail.com', subject, messages.join("\n"));
}
```

- In this case, each value of `message` is splitted by `\n` and it is included in the text body.

#### Reference:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)